# Bulk Save Embedded Image in Excel with Filename on same row

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have list of 500 embedded images in an Excel and need to save them all as original size jpg (images embedded and sized within each cell) with file name on same row.

1st image in C1, file name in D1

2nd image in C2, file name in D2

Found this code below but 2 things need to be modified:

1. this code save images as thumbnails in a cell, resulting in very small images.
2. it saves as "Image01", "Image01", but I need the file names as cell values in column D

Thank you! Any help is appreciated!

```
Sub ExportAllPictures()
    Dim MyChart As Chart
    Dim n As Long, shCount As Long
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim pictureNumber As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    pictureNumber = 1
    For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        shCount = Sht.Shapes.Count
        If Not shCount > 0 Then Exit Sub

        For n = 1 To shCount
            If InStr(Sht.Shapes(n).Name, "Picture") > 0 Then
                'create chart as a canvas for saving this picture
                Set MyChart = Charts.Add
                MyChart.Name = "TemporaryPictureChart"
                'move chart to the sheet where the picture is
                Set MyChart = MyChart.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=Sht.Name)

                'resize chart to picture size
                MyChart.ChartArea.Width = Sht.Shapes(n).Width
                MyChart.ChartArea.Height = Sht.Shapes(n).Height
                MyChart.Parent.Border.LineStyle = 0 'remove shape container border

                'copy picture
                Sht.Shapes(n).Copy

                'paste picture into chart
                MyChart.ChartArea.Select
                MyChart.Paste

                'save chart as jpg
                MyChart.Export Filename:=Sht.Parent.Path & "\Picture-" & pictureNumber & ".jpg", FilterName:="jpg"
                pictureNumber = pictureNumber + 1

                'delete chart
                Sht.Cells(1, 1).Activate
                Sht.ChartObjects(Sht.ChartObjects.Count).Delete
            End If
        Next
    Next Sht
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What does your code do, and what has happened when you tried modifying the code?

Comment: The code saves a "screenshot" of the cell where the images are embedded, so the saved jpg is very small. I haven't modified the code yet because I don't have coding background, so far I've only got to the point where I know how to run it as a vba...

Answer (score 0):

Try this ... May get you on the way Use first column of your sheet as the name you desire, the second is the embedded image.

```
Sub ExportImages_ExtendOffice()
'Updated by Extendoffice 20220308
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xStrImgName As String
    Dim xImg As Shape
    Dim xObjChar As ChartObject
    Dim xFD As FileDialog
    Set xFD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFD.Title = "Please select a folder to save the pictures" & " - ExtendOffice"
    If xFD.Show = -1 Then
       xStrPath = xFD.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each xImg In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If xImg.TopLeftCell.Column = 2 Then
        xStrImgName = xImg.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
        If xStrImgName <> "" Then
            xImg.Select
            
            Selection.Copy
            Set xObjChar = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, xImg.Width, xImg.Height)
            With xObjChar
                .Border.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
                .Activate
                ActiveChart.Paste
                .Chart.Export xStrPath & xStrImgName & ".png"
                .Delete
            End With
        End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).